# iOS set selected background to table row after reload data?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have following issue: I have a UITableView.If you click on a cell, a button is added on cell. No Problem till now... but: After  adding button i want the TableView (after its reload) to select the just edited (or added) TableCell.
I've tried this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
if (bool) {
[cell setSelected:YES animated:YES];
 }
    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:34/255.0 green:139/255.0 blue:34/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
        [bgColorView release];
        return cell;
```

But it didn't work.
Any suggestion or sample code would be appreciated. Thanks .

Comment: Any idea about this, other then Scar's suggestion?Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the standard selection you use the following method, described at UITableView [reference docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
`- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition`

Your design might be improved if you use the custom cell storing information of selection count, that is much better than reloading the table and adding a lot of cell logic outside of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

You can access the selected cell properties and controls without reloading the data using:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Here is some code that can help you:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     [cell.myButton setHidden:false];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm not using custom cell and i've to reloadData becouse i've to perform  some action when row is selected first time and some other action when row is selected second time also i've different content view on cell according to row selection time.